# PhantomJS can't find element by id

Tags: .net, selenium, c#-4.0, phantomjs

I'm using the last version of selenium in my C# console application.

The problem is I have a web site that I can't see the first element to login BUT the same website works fine in firefox

Things I tried:

- Maximize the window: `driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();`
- Checked if the element presented in other frame (No frames in this page).
- Wait till the element will show up / page load.

**One more thing:**

In this website when I check physically on site (view source) the html didn't have the element presentation like it should be, when I check the inspect element I see the html page like it should.

So what do I need to do is that phantomJS will take the html information from the DOM and not like the original page source from the server

How can I solve this problem?

When i using the Internet Explorer Driver its crashed on start (only on this specific website).

How can i solve that problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share your html and C# code

Comment: What PhantomJS version are you using and have you tried others of 1.9.7, 1.9.8 or 2.0.0?

Comment: I using version 2.0.0, No didn't tried the others.

Comment: Tried with older versions still didn't work